# Select statement in mysql using LIKE (pyqt5)

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

Newbie here. Id like to ask What could possibly wrong with this code:

```
'SELECT * FROM A3A_SIS.customer_info WHERE cust_name LIKE %' +self.le_ci_search.text()+ '%'
```

This line returns an error of this:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
I am trying to search a column name where theres a word lopez in it.

UPDATE #1:

I use this code as suggested:

```
def CustSearch(self):
        search_text = '%{}%'.format(self.le_ci_search.text())

        con = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='password',
                        host='localhost', database='A3A_SIS')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            query = ('SELECT * FROM A3A_SIS.customer_info WHERE cust_name LIKE %s', (search_text))

            if cur.execute(query):
                QMessageBox.information(self, "Announcement.","Data was found!")
            else:    
                QMessageBox.information(self, "Announcement.","No data was found!")


        con.close()
```

I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/anthonygaupo/Desktop/A3ASIS/A3A_Func.py", line 409, in
>   CustSearch
>       if cur.execute(query):
>
> File
>   "/Users/anthonygaupo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
>   line 250, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>
> File
>   "/Users/anthonygaupo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorvalue
>
> File
>   "/Users/anthonygaupo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
>   line 247, in execute
>       res = self._query(query)
>
> File
>   "/Users/anthonygaupo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
>   line 411, in _query
>       rowcount = self._do_query(q)
>
> File
>   "/Users/anthonygaupo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
>   line 374, in _do_query
>       db.query(q)
>
> File
>   "/Users/anthonygaupo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 277, in query
>       _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

I am MYSQL workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to put the search text, including the % characters, in quotes.

But you should not do this. Assemble the value outside of the SQL statement and use parameter substitution:

```
query = '%{}%'.format(self.le_ci_search.text())
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM A3A_SIS.customer_info WHERE cust_name LIKE %s', (query,))
```

**Edit**

You're creating a single tuple and passing it to the cursor as the query. What I said to do is to create a string, and pass that plus the parameter to the cursor:

```
cur = con.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM A3A_SIS.customer_info WHERE cust_name LIKE %s'
if cur.execute(query, (search_text,)):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting this error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple' I tried to put str(query) but doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact code you tried and the full traceback. Also, which MySQL client library are you using?

Comment: please check sir. I already edited it. I am using mysql workbench

Comment: The code you've shown wouldn't give that error. But you haven't shown either the full code or the full traceback. Plus, "mysql workbench" is an app, not the client library you are using in Python.

Comment: Im sorry. im using MySQLdb. Edited again above.

Comment: Hello sir! Thank you very much! It finally worked. I have to learn more about this format. I am not totally familiar yet with this. I just like to clarify, why does the comma in "search_text," is needed to convert all arguments? Again, thank you very much!!